MLE and UMVUE from an ordered sample of the exponential distribution
I am having a lot of trouble with every part of the problem below.

Now, finding MLE's is simple in principle. I just find the distribution for $Y$ and then use calculus to find the value of $\sigma$ which minimizes (Edit: maximizes, not minimizes) the distribution for fixed $Y$. Then I plug that value of $\sigma$ into $e^{-t/\sigma}$ and I will be done. The issue is I don't see how to find the distribution of $Y$, or rather, it seems very complicated, at least based on this Wikipedia page on order statistics.
For part (b), I see that $T(Y)=\sum_{i=1}^k Z_i$, but I am not sure how that helps show it is a complete sufficient statistic, nor do I see why $Z_1,\ldots.Z_n$ are i.i.d. exponential. If I know the distribution of $Y$, I could at least use the factorization theorem to show that $T(Y)$ is sufficient.
For the last part, it seems like I should be using the Lehman-Scheffe theorem. That is, if I can find a function $\varphi$ such that $\varphi(T(Y))$ is an unbiased estimator for $e^{-t/\sigma}$ then it will be an UMVUE by Lehman-Scheffe since $T(Y)$ is a complete sufficient statistic by part (b). Using the hint from (b), we know $E(T(Y))=k\sigma$, so the naive choice would be $\varphi(T(Y))=e^{-kt/T(Y)}$, but its not true of course that $E(e^{-kt/T(Y)})=e^{-kt/E(T(Y))}$.
This is not a school assignment or exam. If anyone has any ideas how to handle any part of this question, I would much appreciate it.

Hints about the hint:  1) Do you know what the distribution of the minimum of $n$ exponential variates is?  2) Are you aware of the memoryless property of the exponential distribution?

For (b), check Rényi's representation. UMVUE of survival function of exponential distribution has been routinely covered here as well as in Math.SE; also see Shao's Example 3.3. Then based on these, update your attempts here.
